# Centralize Website and logo

Tags: php, css, wordpress, header

I want my page's logo and articles to be in the center of the site. At the moment everything is on the left.
I just can't make it work.
For Example I tried to delete the wrapper and set margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; in the logo's class. nothing works.

And for the posts i just don't know where to start. probably i would have to put everything in a container and make that central? (There should be three posts in a row, at the moment the theme stacks them up to the right screen border if you have a big screen)

Thank you so much.

**EDIT: The Text align in the image class did the job. Thank you guys, question answered!**

Answer (score 1):

```
#logobild {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

That will do it for you :) Your header takes up 100% of the space, so the content inside has no fixed dimensions to center against. The `text-align` value assists with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#logobild {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: It would seem as if you're a bit late to the party, friend.

Answer (score 0):

To center the logo you can do the following in CSS:

```
img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

The img element is inline by default, which means your margin styles won't be applied to it. When it is set to block level the margin settings will work.

To center the articles I suggest you give a width to the container div like this:

```
#post-area {
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

I'm not sure if that's the best way, but it seems to work.